# Partial derivatives and differentiability of $f(x,y)=(xy)^{1/3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I had a test last week and I failed it. Moreover, my teacher does not want to show the corrected test, and I don't know what I did wrong. So...

What are the partial derivatives of  $f(x,y)=(xy)^{1/3}$ at $(0,0)$? Do partial derivatives exist at the points in the form $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$, with $a,b$ nonzero? And $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you write on this question on the test?

Comment: @Arthur: I calculated the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ using the derivative definition. About differentiability at $(0,0)$, I used a limit (limit of E(h,k)/||(h,k)|| as (h,k)->(0,0)).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $f_x(0,0)$, you need to compute

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(h\cdot 0)^{1/3}-(0\cdot 0)^{1/3}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{h}
$$
This looks like an indeterminate form and one *could* use l'Hopital's rule on it, but instead, observe that this is *always* zero (except when $h$ is zero), so this is the same as $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}=0$.

For $f_y(a,0)$, you need to compute
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a,h)-f(a,0)}{h-a}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(ah)^{1/3}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^{1/3}}{h^{2/3}}.
$$
In this case, the denominator is going to zero while the numerator is constant.  This limit diverges (to $\infty$).

Comment: And when $(a,0)$ or $(0,b)$, any hint?

Comment: If you follow the same pattern for $f_x(a,0)$, what do you get?